# How do i fix the react useEffect problem?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Iam a new to react and recently i just have just been practicing react by making a simple shopping cart functionality

this is part of the code i get the error from:

```
const MainShop = () => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const [category, setCategory] = useState('');
  const [sort, setSort] = useState('');
  const [filteredProducts, setFilteredProducts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchItems = async () => {
      const data = await fetch('https://fakestoreapi.com/products');
      const items = await data.json();
      console.log(items);
      setProducts(items);
      setFilteredProducts(products);
    };
    fetchItems();
  }, []);
```

the error says:
Line 42:6:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'products'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. You can also replace multiple useState variables with useReducer if 'setFilteredProducts' needs the current value of 'products'  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

how do i solve this problem?

Comment: It depends on how often you want the `useEffect` callback to run.

Comment: setFilteredProducts(products) - but what are we trying to do here . should this be something like `setFilteredProducts(items.filter(based on some condition))`

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you should first learn what is `useEffect` Dependency Array. Also in your question define the states you are using and where are you getting `products` what is the difference with fetched `items`. If they are different is it necessary to keep them in the same `useEffect` hook? Note that you can have several effect hooks in one component with different dependencies array

But as a fast hack, if you want the fetch to be triggered only once when the component mounts, disable the dependency error like below.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchItems = async () => {
      const data = await fetch('https://fakestoreapi.com/products');
      const items = await data.json();
      console.log(items);
      setProducts(items);
      setFilteredProducts(products);
    };
    fetchItems();
   // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);
```

If according to filters the fetch should be triggered again

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchItems = async () => {
      const data = await fetch(`https://fakestoreapi.com/products?filter=${filters}`);
      const items = await data.json();
      console.log(items);
      setProducts(items);
      setFilteredProducts(products);
    };
    fetchItems();
  }, [filters]);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, i think first i will dig deep into useEffect and dependency array

Comment: thank you for the answer, sorry to respond you this late, yeah now i've understood how i should use useEffect in every type of case